# Jhipster : Dealing with model update and front-end changes

Tags: jhipster

I'm using Jhipster since one month and my application start to be quite big.

I'm wondering something, when I need to update my model via JDL, a lot of files are overriden. For the moment I answer "no" when Jhipster ask me about the files I modified.

But what is the best practice in Jhipster ? Do you modify your front-end in the same file as default generated files ? Do you create new file to separatly change the look of your pages ? My question is global for the front-end this is why I don't have precise examples.

Thanks

Comment: I rely mostly on git branching and merging with this strategy: `git merge -s recursive -Xours ...` see https://gist.github.com/gmarziou/6cc0788f8e7cb21a61a7b14f32b9a657

Comment: You may find useful this presentation https://youtu.be/9WVpwIUEty0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's what I wanted !